# Cyclic permutation group example ($n>1$)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I have googled around and haven't been able to find any examples of some $S_n$ with $n>1$ that is a cyclic group. This may mean it is a dumb question, any help is appreciated.

Comment: $S_2$ is cyclic, but for $n\geq 3$ $S_n$ isn't even abelian.

Comment: ok, how can i convince myself of that? Would thinking about permutations of plane objects help? I mean for n bigger than or equal to 3, $S_2$ is just $Z_2$

Comment: Well $(12)(13)\neq (13)(12)$. Just about any pair of permutations you write down won't commute.

Comment: "$\mathcal{S}_n$ is *very* not abelian" - words to live by

Comment: @MichaelTong haha, fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cyclic permutation group refers to a subgroup of $S_{n}$ that is cyclic. Examples here are easy. Just pick a single permutation and examine the group it generates.

Comment: this is at odds with the commented answer above, is there a terminology issue?

Comment: @qbert The comment above claims that $S_n$ is not cyclic for $n \geq 3$, which is true. However, for each $n$, $S_n$ certainly has cyclic subgroups.

Comment: ok, so i should have asked is $S_n$ cyclic for $n>1$. Sorry

Comment: $S_2$ is also trivially a subgroup of itself. :-)